# How/When did Liz learn about Kirito's Duel Wield?

Tags: sword-art-online

Near the end of Episode 9 after Kirito killed The Gleam Eyes, he's complaining about how he can't go back to his place because everyone is hounding him about his Dual Wield Skill, Liz then shows up saying

> It was our little secret until you blabbed about it

Implying that she knew about his Dual Wield before hand, however when Kirito got Liz to commission his second sword she never asked what it was for. Considering that Kirito was hiding his Dual Wield and it didn't come out until the boss battle how did Liz find out?

Comment: I didn't even notice that Liz might've known earlier. Guess I have to go over that episode again tonight. :)

Comment: I just rewatched that episode. Yeah, it doesn't say how and when she learned about it.

Comment: If i remember correctly, I think the novel goes into more detail on it, ill have to scan through it before I can answer tho

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the novel, after Lisbeth made the sword (and before Asuna barged in), she did ask him what he needed it for:

"Speaking of which— In the beginning, you did say, a sword equal to this one, didn't you. That white one certainly is a good sword, but I don't think there's much difference with that monster dropped one. Why would you need two swords resembling each other?"
"Aah..."
Kirito turned about, staring at me with an expression that showed that he was hesitating over something.
"Well, I can't explain everything. If you won't ask any further than that, I can tell you."
....

And then he showed his skill to Lisbeth. The anime skips this entirely.